# BibTeX and TeXworks on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: bibtex

I've been trying to create a bibliography for my thesis, but I really haven't been able to. I have read almost the entire forum  with all your suggestions, but still it doesn't work.

I have: `\usepackage{cite}` and I am in a `\documentclass{srcbook}`

I have a folder where I have my main `thesis.tex` and within this folder I have one folder `Text`, where I have my single chapters, that I include in my main `thesis.tex` file with `\include`.

The file created with BibTeX is together with the main `thesis.tex` file but when I compile with the green arrow in TeXworks I have lots of warnings. i tried to put everything together in a folder, but it still doesn't work.   These are some of the warnings:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013)
The top-level auxiliary file: Bachelorarbeit.aux
I couldn't open style file abbrev.bst
---line 2 of file Bachelorarbeit.aux
 : \bibstyle{abbrev
 :                 }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
A level-1 auxiliary file: Text/Theory.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Text/BoundaryConditions.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Text/CylinderFlow.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Text/InitialConditions.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Text/GridVariations.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Text/NumericalResults.aux
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 16 of file Bachelorarbeit.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {plain}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file Bachelorarbeit.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

This warning comes when I compile using BibTeX in the scrolling box in TeXworks. I have tried also different bibliography styles (`plain`, `abbrev`, etc) , but I can't achieve to have my bibliography.

Does anyone of you can urgently help me figure this out. I really need to get my thesis, but I really can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The bibliography style name is `abbrv`; the error messages show also that you have two `\bibliographystyle` commands, which is not allowed.